# How can i get ID of any widget outside the MainActivity.java class file?

Tags: java, android

I want to fetch information from MySQL database and display it in a ListView for this purpose i write code in separate class whose name is "BackgroundWorker.java". I'm getting everything from the database but I don't know how can i get id of TextView widget of my layout file in "BackgroundWorker" class to display result.

MainActivity.java code

```
new BackgroundWorker(this).execute()
```

BackgroundWorker.java code

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //here i want to get id of layout widget to display result
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried. We have no idea what "BackgroundWorker" is and how it relates to the rest of your code.

Comment: edited bro let me know if you got it?

Comment: I would not describe that as "complete". Using an `AsyncTask` from an `Activity` does not work well, as it will not handle configuration changes, such as when the user rotates the screen. The book you read on Android app development, or the course you took on Android app development, should show you better patterns for background work. If you have not read a book on Android app development, you can download older versions of [one of my books](https://commonsware.com) on [this page](https://commonsware.com/Android/4-2-free).

Comment: Have a look my asnwer

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem, Android offers `WeakReference`, that you can get the reference to anything you want if you can manipulate this class

```
private static class SampleTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>{
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;
    MainActivity activity;

    SampleTask(MainActivity context)
    {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);

    }

    //....
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing())
        {
            return;
        }
        //Now you have the activity you can access your fields including 

    }
}
```

[Visit here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference) for more and detailed info